# How to make labels change dynamically due to textbox's value in gridview, and calculate its sum?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have 1 `textbox` and 2 `label` (
**lblPrice, lblSubTotal**) *inside* every row in a `gridview`, and 1 `label` (**lblTotal**) *outside* of the gridView:

**aspx.cs**

```
//GridView
<asp:GridView ID="productView" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="productView_SelectedIndexChanged">

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPrice"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subtotal">            
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSubTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

</asp:GridView>

//label outside GridView
<asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
```

**aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List <decimal> newa = new List<decimal>();
        newa.Add(10);
        newa.Add(20);
        newa.Add(30);
        newa.Add(40);

        GridView1.DataSource = newa;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Label label1 = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblPrice") as Label;
            label1.Text = newa[i].ToString();
        }
    }
```

The value of `lblTotal` and `lblSubTotal` changes whenever the `textbox` value is changed with the formula of:

> lblSubTotal = textbox * lblPrice
>
> lblTotal = lblSubTotal(row[0]) + .....  lblSubTotal(row[gridview.count-1])

I have tried creating the **script** of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= textbox.ClientID %>').keyup(function () {
         var sum = parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($('#<%= lblPrice.ClientID %>').html());
    $('#<%= lblSubTotal.ClientID %>').html(sum);
});
</script>
```

But the script couldn't identify the `textbox`, `lblPrice` and `lblSubTotal`. What can I do to make them identifiable? Also, what kind of script could I use to calculate the `lblTotal`?

Comment: Can you provide layout from the `GridView` (which column contains textbox and which ones using label)? You need to iterate through rows of gridview and then use `$("input[id*=textbox]").value` to get value from  those textboxes, since gridview uses repeated control naming scheme during rendering controls in client-side.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Done updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using simple jQuery selectors like:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("[id$=textbox]").keyup(function () {
             var sum = parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($("[id$=lblPrice]").html());
        $("[id$=lblSubTotal]").html(sum);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: the script didn't fire

Comment: I have forgotten to close the script bracket, hope you didn't?

Comment: Your newly given script in comment is also not working @bojidar.lyutskanov

Comment: Yes, I just realized that your controls are run at server, therefore you have to use jquery selectors specifying you are looking for ids and I changed my answer. Could you please try my suggestion. I hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Since `txtAmount`, `lblPrice` and `lblSubTotal` exists inside GridView rows, you can't access them directly using `ClientID` due to multiple controls with different `ClientID`s exist, hence you need to use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/). This implementation below adopted from [Mudassar Khan's article](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calculate-Row-Total-and-Grand-Total-in-ASPNet-GridView-using-jQuery.aspx) with some changes based from GridView structure:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var totals = 0;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // use keyup event with attribute equals selector
        $("[id*=textbox]").live("keyup", function () {
            if (!$.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                if (!isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
                    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                    $("[id*=lblSubTotal]", row).html(parseInt($("[id*=lblPrice]", row).html()) * parseInt($(this).val()));
                }
            }
            else {
                $(this).val('');
            }

            // sum every subtotals to form grand total
            $("[id*=lblSubTotal]").each(function () {
                totals = totals + parseInt($(this).html());
            });

            // lblTotal is placed outside the gridview, thus you can use ClientID for it
            var lblTotal = $("<%= lblTotal.ClientID %>");
            lblTotal.html(totals.toString());
        });
    });
</script>
```

The difference between original implementation & this implementation is reflected in usage of `TemplateField` containing `lblPrice` in OP's GridView instead of a `BoundField` with predefined CSS class.

NB: You can use `parseFloat` besides of `parseInt` when dealing with float values in `lblPrice` & `lblSubTotal` (using cents).